# How can I determine whether a UK company trades internationally

Tags: accounting

Can anyone think of ways to determine whether a UK company trades internationally?

I have seen that possibly if the have 'GB' at the start of their VAT number.

Can any financial ratios signal this?

Comment: Do you mean to ask for a way to determine if the company's equity trades on international exchanges or that the company engages in importing and exporting?

Comment: engaging in importing and exporting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HM Revenue & Customs has some lists of importers exporters that you can download...

https://www.uktradeinfo.com/Statistics/Pages/DataDownloads.aspx

But I am not sure if they have any easy way to browse them apart from downloading the files.

Comment: Thanks a great answer!